# Having trouble getting Entity's "child" loaded via @Query in Sprint Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have an entity like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Move {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;

    @Property("placement")
    private String placement;

    @Relationship(type="PARENT", direction=Relationship.INCOMING)
    BoardPosition parent;

    @Relationship("CHILD")
    BoardPosition child;

    [...]
```

When I "load" it like this:

```
Move the_move = m_store.findByPlacement("C1");
log.info("Move direct load: " + the_move.toString());
```

it works fine.   Both the `parent` and `child` properties have the correct value.

However, when I access it via a query defined like this:

```
public interface MoveStore extends Neo4jRepository<Move, Long> {
    public Move findByPlacement(String placement);
    @Query("MATCH (n:Move) RETURN n")
    public List<Move> findAll();
```

and accessed like this:

```
ListIterator<Move> moves = m_store.findAll().listIterator();

while(moves.hasNext() ) {
    log.info(moves.next().toString());
}
```

it is missing the `child` value (is null).

This experiment is strange:

```
while(moves.hasNext() ) {
    Move m = moves.next();
    log.info(m.toString());  // This is missing m.child's value
    // find the same Move, by passing in the id of this one:
    m = m_store.findById(m.id).orElse(null);
    log.info(m.toString());  // This has the correct value for m.child!
}
```

What am I missing?  How can I make the query load the child property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the custom query, you have also to return the relationship and related nodes to get the child populated.

e.g. `@Query("MATCH (n:Move)-[rel:CHILD]-(c:BoardPosition) RETURN n, rel, c")` would do the job for a 1:1 relationship otherwise a `collect(...)` is needed to get the list in the same result "row" as the node you are querying for.

Comment: This works.  Thanks!!   But it still seems very mysterious.  Why did I have to do this to get the `child` property filled on the `Move` but the `Parent` property filled just fine?

Comment: Also the `Parent` shouldn't get populated because Neo4j-OGM does not know about it. If you just return the `Move` in the custom query, there is no chance to see the other nodes. Maybe it's some leftover from the cache if you run the loop in a transaction.